# GORM UpdateAll reference property

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm

I'm not that familiar with Grails or GORM (it's a legacy project we barely ever touch).

My problem: I need to update all objects matching a query and the update essentially needs to reference another property of the object and copy from one property to a different property. Another challenge is the search and update has to be done atomically to avoid problems. As a db we're using mongodb (if that changes anything).

```
//Example: account has three properties: A, B and C
DetachedCriteria<Account> query = Account.where {
  A: "something"
}
query.updateAll(
   B: C //how to reference C here?
)
```

How can I reference C in updateAll? If that's even possible?
I'm not locked on using DetachedCriteria either. Whatever solution fits the best.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest solution would be to use the "low-level" mongo query:

```
Account.collection.updateMany( [ A:'something' ], [ $set:[ A:'something else', B:42 ] ] )
```

You have to check though, that you have `updateMany` method in your version of mongo plugin / mongo driver. You might end up having:

```
Account.collection.update( [ A:'something' ], [ $set:[ A:'something else', B:42 ] ], [ multi:1 ] )
```

Comment: That was not totally on point, but since I only needed to $rename the property anyway (not copy), it worked. Thanks